# Inequality of integral : $\int_0^{1}((\sqrt{3}f(x))^{2}-2(f(x)^{3})dx≤1$

Tags: inequality, integral-inequality, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, holder-inequality

If $f(x)>0$ be continue function then this inequality true ?

a) $\int_0^{1}((\sqrt{3}f(x))^{2}-2(f(x)^{3})dx≤1$

b) $(\int_0^{1}\sqrt{3}f(x))^{2}-\int_0^{1}2f(x)^{3}dx≤1$
I was used Cauchy Schwartz inequality but I don't get it

How I can learning integral inequality if any one have a good book tell me .

Comment: Any integral must be less than or equal to the integrands maximum value multiplied by the range of integration. The integrands maximum value is $1$ because the maximum value of $g(x)=3x^2-2x^3$ where $x\gt0$ is $g(1)=1$ and the range of integration is $1$. Hence the integral is at a maximum for $f(x)=1$ where the integral equals $1$.

Answer (score 0):

If $3-2f(x)<0$, so it's obvious.

But for $3-2f(x)\geq0$ by AM-GM we obtain:
$$\int\limits_0^1(3f(x)^2-2f(x)^3)dx\leq\int\limits_0^1\left(\frac{f(x)+f(x)+3-2f(x)}{3}\right)^3dx=1.$$
Because $$\int\limits_0^1\left(\left(\frac{f(x)+f(x)+3-2f(x)}{3}\right)^3-\left(3f(x)^2-2f(x)^3\right)\right)dx\geq0.$$

Comment: Thank you sir @Michael Rozenberg , Here i can use Am-Gm ?? $(\int_0^{1}\sqrt{3}f(x))^{2}-\int_0^{1}2f(x)^{3}dx≤1$

Comment: @Iza Bila Because the integral of non-negative function is non-negative. I added something. See now.

Comment: Yes! Thanks for explaine , Sir can you see inequality b)?